# Ajustar contenido a un contenedor con altura definida

Tags: html, css

Estoy realizando un footer con una altura definida. Sin embargo, el contenido dentro de este footer no "cabe" dada una altura establecida (`height: 23rem;`) ¿Cómo podría "forzar" a que entre a la altura deseada ?

HTML:

```
<footer class="footer">
        <div class="footer_bg">
            <div class="footer_container">
                <div class="footer-logo">
                 <img class="logo-footer" src="img/logo-nav.png" alt="Logo Footer">
                </div>


            <ul class="footer_links">
                <li>
                    <a href="#services" class="footer_link">Servicios</a>
                </li>
               
                <li>
                    <a href="#contact" class="footer_link">Contacto</a>
                </li>
            </ul>

            <div class="footer_socials">
                <a href="https://www.facebook.com/casade.restauracion.1428" target="_blank" class="footer_social">
                <i class="uil uil-facebook"></i>
                </a>
              
                <a href="" target="_blank" class="footer_social">
                    <i class="uil uil-whatsapp"></i>
                </a>

            </div>
            </div>
         </div>
</footer>
```

CSS:

```
.footer_bg {
    background-color: #4E7279;
    height: 23rem;
    padding: 2rem 0 3rem;
}

.footer-logo img {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    width: 18rem;
    margin: auto;
    
}

.footer_links li {
    padding-top: 1rem;
    font-size: 2rem;
}

.footer_socials {
   display: flex;
   justify-content: center;
   align-items: center;
   font-size: 4rem;
   gap: 7rem;
}
```

Comment: Tu código es insuficiente para ver el problema. Además no se entiende, si footer es de height: 23rem, porque no le subes el height y ya???

Answer (score 1):

Lo que se puede hacer para lograr lo que quieres es usar la propiedad min-height , esto permite que tu elemento tenga una altura definida pero aumente con respecto al contenido.

```
.footer_bg {
  background-color: #4E7279;
  min-height: 23rem;//Reemplaza height por min-height
  padding: 2rem 0 3rem;
}
```

En este [Enlace](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_dim_min-height.asp) te dejo mas documentacion de la propiedad min-heigth.